# Proxy in selenium with headless chrome Webdriver (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, scrapy

I'm trying to set proxy on selenium-webdriver.
I tried different methods, I think there are some changes for setting proxy in chrome headless.
can anyone help me?

these are the methods I tried.

First

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxyType = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.autodetect = False
proxy.httpProxy = proxy.sslProxy = proxy.socksProxy = "PROXY_ADDRESS"
options.Proxy = proxy
options.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/nisaf/chromedriver', 
                          chrome_options=options)
```

Second

````
proxy = "PROXY_ADDRESS" 

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('http://www.test.com/proxy-test')```

thanx in advance
````